# Socket io on a https domain that uses proxy pass apache

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io

I have a domain named https://www.example.com (for example)

The site I developed is in mean stack. The site is on running on the port http://localhost:3000

I am using socket io on the admin side and socket io client on the client side for real time data sharing feature.

```
// BACKEND
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

and

```
// FRONTEND
this.socket = io.connect();
```

I with no success is able to establish this real time connection between front end and back end.

I have tried many solution but could not get an answer to this?

I tried the below connection on the front end

```
this.socket = io.connect('wss://<ip-address>:3000', {
                transports: ['websocket'],
            });
```

But could not get the connection to work as well, it is saying time out error

The [github](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942) page is discussing the same issue, but i didn't get a solution from there

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will be interesting to share your apache proxy pass configuration. If you are using the proxy pass and your apache server is configured using standard ports 80 and 443, you shouldn't use the port 3000 in the connection from the frontend, the proxy pass should send you all the traffic to your local server at port 3000.

Comment: so what do you need for that?